# Dual specialization in SWTOR

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In World of Warcraft you can change between two specializations, is there something like this in SWTOR?
As an example, can I play as bounty hunter mercenary arsenal , then switch to bodyguard?

Comment: You can respec once a week, or more if you pay, but I'm guessing you're looking for something more concurrent than that.

Comment: @MatthewRead it is nice have a week respec, I didn't know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Not currently they plan on adding this in the near future.](http://www.swtor.com/blog/community-qa-april-27th-2012#e)

**From the Q&A Blog:**

> **Lovarboy: Will we get dual spec with Game Update 1.3?**
>
> **Daniel:** Unfortunately, no. Game Update 1.3 is being kept a bit leaner to get the Group Finder and the next stage of Legacy in the game as fast as possible. After that we’ll be returning to some bigger updates and we’re hoping dual spec makes it for the next one.